# Collecting fountain particles on ground to fill up screen at every click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, p5.js

```js
var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles = $('.particles'),
    particleCount = 0,
    sizes = [
       25, 35, 45
    ],
    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],
    
    mouseX = $w.width() / 2, mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticleCount () {
  $('.particle-count > .number').text(particleCount);
};

$w
.on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$d
.on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $d
    .one('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
      clearInterval( timer );
    })
    createParticle( event );
  }, 1000 / 60)
  
});


function createParticle ( event ) {
  var particle = $('<div class="particle"/>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 10,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 25,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((36 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime = (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;
  
  particle
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
  })
  .appendTo( particles );
  particleCount++;
  updateParticleCount();
  
  var particleTimer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;
    
    
    particle
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + .25,
     transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
     webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });
    
    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle.remove();
    particleCount--;
      updateParticleCount();
      clearInterval(particleTimer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 50);  
}
```

I have fountain particles in Javascript. When I click on screen some particles releases and disappears. I want them to get gather on the ground to get collected on every click in javascript, not to get disappeared.

like i click once some particles come and get collected on the ground, on next click some more come from fountain and get stored in the ground and this process keep going untill the screen fills up to the half. once it at half it should get disappearing from the bottom of the ground.

Comment: You should provide code sample and specify your question.

Comment: Attached the JS Code

Comment: Can you please narrow your question down to a [mcve] instead of your entire project? And what exactly is your question? You've posted your goal, but you haven't told us where you're stuck.